# AWS access key file error - Required option '-O, --aws-access-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, ec2-api-tools

I am trying to execute a bash script to fetch the ec2 cost details from aws. while executing the script i get the following eror

```
Required option '-O, --aws-access-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)
```

I have exported the keys inside my script as well as using "aws configure"

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FIL="~/.aws/config"
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_PROFILES_FILE="~/.aws/credentials"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*******************
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*******************************
```

but still i get the same error. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if you are using the .aws/credentials why you set the access key and secret too?

Comment: @cmnardi I am using either of them i meant to say i tried both possibilities but still not working.

Comment: `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` in the bash script before calling cost details just to make sure it is correctly set. Or use `aws configure` and set your credentials.

Comment: @helloV  yes its set perfectly..

Comment: Add `set -x` at the beginning of the script and find out which command is complaining